# RegEx expression not allowing only spaces?

Tags: regex

I have this regEx expression which allows only spaces, letters and dashes. I'd like to modify it so it wouldn't allow ONLY spaces too. Can someone help me ?

```
/^([A-zăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ-\s])+$/
```

Comment: Move the `-` to the end or beginning of the character class. Knowing the language you are using this in would also help.

Comment: @chris85 thanks - didn't know that

Comment: Well, I doubt it is elasticsearch where the `-` should only be placed at the start of the character class to be parsed as a literal symbol, moving it to the end of the character class should also work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to restrict this generic pattern:

```
/^(?!\s+$)[A-Za-zăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ\s-]+$/
  ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE6lB2/1)

The `(?!\s+$)` lookahead is executed once at the very beginning and returns false if there are 1 or more whitespaces until the end of the string.

Also, your regex contained a classical issue of `[A-z]` that matches more than just ASCII letters, you need to replace this with `[A-Za-z]` (or just `[a-z]` and use the `/i` case insensitive modifier).

Also, the `-` inside a character class is usually placed at the end so as not to escape it, and it will be parsed as a literal hyphen (however, you might want to escape it if another developer will have to update this pattern by adding more symbols to the character class).

And just in case this is a regex engine that does not support lookarounds:

```
^[A-Za-zăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ\s-]*[A-Za-zăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ-][A-Za-zăâîșțĂÂÎȘȚ\s-]*$
```

It requires at least 1 non-space character from the allowed set (also matching 1 obligatory symbol).

[Another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE6lB2/2)

Comment: Also, the capturing group here makes no sense, I removed the `(` and `)` from around the pattern, unless you really need the last character for further manipulations.